# %%javascript does not work in Jupyter notebook at windows

Tags: javascript, python, windows, jupyter-notebook

In my own computer (Mac) I start like this in the Jupyter Notebook so it has some extensions that I like. 
[image: Starting cell]

In other computer (Windows 7) it allows me to do that (i dont get any error) but nothing happens.

I searched in the internet and I couldnt find a good solution for this.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure on your Windows 7 computer, the set of community-contributed extensions is installed? See [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-the-python-package) for how to install it. Later in that document, you'll also see a couple of ways of how to enable them in a richer way that may provide more informative feedback on your Windows machine, see [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#enabling-disabling-extensions).